# OnClick function - difference between passing function or wrapping said function in another callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures

I am curious if there is any difference between the following 2 implementations:

```
<Button onClick={handleClick} />
```

and

```
<Button onClick={() => handleClick()} />
```

Let's assume the handleClick function is

```
const handleClick = () => return 5;
```

As far as I can tell, both are callbacks passed to the onClick event, but the first executes handleClick directly and then returns 5, while the second one executes the anonymous function which in turn calls handleClick, which returns 5 to the anonymous function, which will also return 5 (since it's an arrow function with an implicit return).

So really, I am not clear if there are any subtle differences here I am not aware of, or if my logic is flawed in any way.

Comment: The subtle difference is that in a class based component, the longer version binds the component instance to the `handleClick` method, meaning you can use `this` inside.

Comment: The second one generates an anonymous function each reander,which is a small but unnecessary overhead. Most importantly it is a new prop value,so will trigger re-render on the child component. So you generally want to use the first option (with useCallback in functional components) for better optimisation